# Depreciation Basis on Purchased Commercial Foreclosure

Tags: real-estate, cost-basis, purchase, depreciation, foreclosure

I've hit a roadblock in my research on the use/abuse of TIFs. I've asked some professionals the below question, however, none were willing to answer or gave me conflicting answers.

The question: What is the GAAP basis for depreciation for the new owner of a commercial building purchased out of foreclosure? Say, a building built for $1 million having a 15-year depreciation schedule that at three-years-old is purchased out of foreclosure for, say, $500 thousand. Is the basis for the new owner still the original $1 million or the $500 thousand?

I've tried to answer this myself, but have not been able to filter out the myriad of non-related results associated with "depreciation."

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The foreclosure and the original building costs do not seem to be relevant.

> *Property acquired by purchase.* The depreciable basis is equal to the
> asset's purchase price, minus any discounts, and plus any sales taxes,
> delivery charges, and installation fees. For real estate, you can also
> include costs of legal and accounting fees, revenue stamps, recording
> fees, title abstracts/insurance, surveys, and real estate taxes
> assumed for the seller. Remember you can only depreciate the
> buildings—land is never depreciable.

> *Land and building acquired in a single transaction.* A business will
> frequently acquire both land and an office building. In these cases,
> only the portion of the price that is attributed to the building is
> depreciable.

https://www.wolterskluwer.com/en/expert-insights/determining-basis-is-first-step-in-depreciation-computation